# The centroid problem of a plane geometry (using integral)

Tags: integration, geometry

Let D be a thin slice with a radius of R, and L be a tangent to D. The point density of any point P on D is proportional to the square of the distance d from P to L, and the proportional coefficient K>0. Find the position of the center of mass of the slice.

I am confused about the steps to find the center of mass.

Comment: Perhaps you would find this more fitting in Physics SE?

Comment: A thin slice means a lot of things to me. What does it mean to you?  A segment of a circular disk? A diagram is desirable.

Comment: You could think of it that way

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sector]

The object, of which the center of mass is sought, is assumed to be a thin circular sector having a radius $R$ and a thickness $t$. The given tangent, which controlled the point-densities, touches the outer edge of the sector at $C$ (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$). The arc $AB$ subtends an angle $\phi$ at its center $O$. The radius $OC$ make an angle $\omega$ with the $x$-axis. Selected arbitrary point $P$ lies on this sector a distance of $r$ from $O$ and $\measuredangle POA$ is equal to $\alpha$. Therefore, $P$ has the coordinates $\left(r\cos\alpha, r\sin\alpha\right)$. Let the density at $P$ be $\rho$.

$\underline{\mathbf{\large{1}}.}\space\mathrm{Finding\space Density\space at\space an\space Arbitrary\space Point}$

First of all, we need to express $\rho$ in terms of $R, K,$ and $r$. We drop two perpendiculars $PH$ and $PQ$ to $OC$ and the tangent respectively. Now, we have,
$$OH = r\cos \left(\omega - \alpha\right)\space\rightarrow\space b = CH = R- r\cos \left(\omega - \alpha\right).$$

$$\therefore\quad \rho = Kb^2 = K\bigl[R-r\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)\bigr]^2. \tag{1}$$

$\underline{\mathbf{\large{2}}.}\space\mathrm{Finding\space Weight\space and\space Moment\space of\space a\space Small\space Section}$

Next, we are going to determine the volume $\Delta V$ of the small section $DEFG$ of the sector shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$.
$$\Delta  V = \left[\frac{1}{2} \left(r+\frac{1}{2}\Delta r\right)^2\Delta\alpha - \frac{1}{2} \left(r-\frac{1}{2}\Delta r\right)^2\Delta\alpha\right]t \approx r\cdot t\cdot \Delta r\cdot \Delta\alpha. \tag{2}$$

As shown below, using (1) and (2), we can express the weight $\Delta W$ of the section $DEFG$ and its moment $\Delta M_x$ about the $x$-axis.
$$\Delta W = \rho\Delta V \approx K\cdot t\cdot r \bigl[R-r\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)\bigr]^2 \Delta r\cdot \Delta\alpha \tag{3}$$
$$\Delta M_x = \Delta W\times PN \approx K\cdot t\cdot r^2 \bigl[R-r\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)\bigr]^2\sin \left(\alpha\right) \Delta r\cdot \Delta\alpha \tag{4}$$

$\underline{\mathbf{\large{3}}.}\space\mathrm{Finding\space Total\space Weight\space of\space the\space Sector}$

The total weight $W$ of the thin circular sector can be found by carrying out the following integration.
$$W= \int\Delta W = \int^{\phi}_{0}\int^{R}_{0} K\cdot t\cdot r \Bigl[R-r\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)\Bigr]^2 dr\cdot d\alpha$$

Since $r$ and $\alpha$ do not depend on each other, we shall expand the expression to be integrated and write it as two independent integrations, one inside the other, as shown below
$$W = K\cdot t \int^{\phi}_{0}\Biggl[\int^{R}_{0} \Bigl\{R^2r^2-2Rr^2\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)+r^3\cos^2\left(\omega - \alpha \right)\Bigr\} dr\Biggr] d\alpha.$$

Once we do the inside integration, it reduces to
$$W =K\cdot t\int^{\phi}_{0}\left[\frac{1}{2}R^2 r^2-\frac{2}{3}Rr^3\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)+\frac{1}{4}\cos^2\left(\omega - \alpha \right) \right]^{R}_{0} d\alpha,$$
and, then, to
$$W = \frac{1}{12}K\cdot R^4\cdot  t \int^{\phi}_{0} \Bigl\{6-8\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)+3\cos^2\left(\omega - \alpha \right)\Bigr\}d\alpha.$$

We need to expand the $3^{rd}$ term to obtain
$$W = \frac{1}{24}K\cdot R^4\cdot t \int^{\phi}_{0} \Bigl\{15-16\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)+3\cos\left(2\omega - 2\alpha \right)\Bigr\}d\alpha.$$

When we integrate this, we get
$$W = \frac{1}{48}K\cdot R^4\cdot t \biggl[30\alpha+32\sin\left(\omega - \alpha \right)-3\sin\left(2\omega - 2\alpha \right)\biggr]^{\phi}_{0}.$$

$$\therefore\quad W=\frac{1}{48}K\cdot R^4\cdot t \Bigl\{30\phi-32\sin\left(\omega - \phi \right) - 3\sin\left(2\omega – 2\phi\right)+32\sin\left(\omega\right)\\ - 3\sin \left(2\omega\right)\Bigr\}. \tag{5}$$

$\underline{\mathbf{\large{4}}.}\space\mathrm{Finding\space Total\space Moment\space of\space the\space Sector\space about\space the\space \it{x-}Axis}$

The total moment about the $x$-axis, i.e. $M_x$, of the thin circular sector can be found by carrying out the integration given below.
$$M_x = \int\Delta M_x = K\cdot t\int^{\phi}_{0}\Biggl[\int^{R}_{0} \Bigl(R-r\cos\left(\omega - \alpha \right)\Bigr)^2r^2  dr\Biggr]\sin\left(\alpha\right)  d\alpha$$

This yields the following expression for $M_x$.
$$M_x = \frac{1}{12}K\cdot R^5\cdot t\biggl[ 52\bigl\{1-\cos\left(\phi\right)\bigr\} -30\phi\sin\left(\omega\right)+15\cos\left(\omega - 2\phi\right)\\ + 6\cos\left(2\omega - \phi\right) - 2\cos\left(\omega - 3\phi\right) - 13\cos\left(\omega\right) -6\cos\left(2\omega\right)\biggl] \tag{6}$$

$\underline{\mathbf{\large{5}}.}\space\mathrm{Finding\space Coordinates \space of\space the\space Sector’s\space center\space of\space Gravity}$

If we denote the $y$-coordinate of the sector’s center of gravity as $y_G$, then, it can be calculated using (5}, (6) and the following relationship.
$$y_G = \frac{M_x}{W} \tag{7}$$
Now, it is up to the OP, that is you by the way, to find an expression for $M_y$ - the total moment about the $y$-axis – and, then, calculate the $x$-coordinate of the sector’s center of gravity using a relationship similar to (7).

We are still in want of the $z$-coordinate of the sector’s center of gravity $z_G$. However, finding it does not pose any difficulty. Since we have assumed that the thin sector has a uniform thickness $t$,
$$z_G = \frac{1}{2}t. \tag{8}$$

$\underline{\mathbf{\large{6}}.}\space\mathrm{A\space Test\space Case}$

It is always advisable to verify the validity of mathematically derived results using  known cases. The selected case here is the thin disk, where we have $\phi = 2\pi$ (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 3}$). It is obvious that the point-density distribution is symmetrical about the diameter $CD$, whatever value is chosen for $\omega$. Therefore, disk’s center of gravity is located on that particular diameter. This becomes even more evident if we choose $\omega = 0^O$, because, then, the CG lies on the $x$-axis, making $y_G = 0$. Let us check our formulae (5), (6), and (7).

$$W = \frac{5}{4}KtR^4\pi \qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad M_x = 0 \quad\rightarrow\quad y_G = \frac{M_x}{W} = \frac{0}{\frac{5}{4}KtR^4\pi}=0 $$
You are welcome to perform the same test for any $\omega$, once you obtain an expression for $x_G$.

$\mathrm{Fig.\space 4}$ is the 3D-plot of the point-density distribution of a disk when $\omega = 0^{o}$. It has the shape of a parabolic dish antenna. Interestingly enough, when we add the disk to the picture, the resulting object resembles a chopped-off cylinder with a flat base and the mentioned dish at top. We think that the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of this solid cylinder is the same as that of our thin disk.

[image: 3DPlots]